# Different results between using double for loop and input one by one

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I am a beginner in Python. 
I am coding for loop, double loop in python.
but there were 2 different results when I write for loop and input one by one.
I don't know how do I call this issue.
so, I was not able to search proper question here.
would you please check my code?

my code below

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
train =  pd.read_csv('file', delimiter='\t')

s =train['A'] # s = sentences splited by spacy.sentencizer
a =[]
for x in range(len(s))):
    newlist = []
    for y in range(len(s[x])):
        newlist.append(len(s[x][y].text))
    a.append(newlist)

d=[]
newlist2=[]
for f in range(len(a)):
    for g in range(len(a[f])):
        if sum(a[f][0:g+1]) >= 50:      
            newlist2.append(g)   # I need only min value if more 1 result
    d.append(min(news))
```

so, I got this result:

```
d[:12]
>>>[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0] #(after then, **all result is 0**)
```

but, what I need is like below:

```
d[:12]
>>>[2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1] #(this is example, not real result)
```

my trouble is that
when h>10, **every result is 0**.

but when I input `len(a[13]) in 'for g in range(len(a[f]))'`,the result is correct I want, instead of using for loop `(for f in range(len(a)))`

I wonder that there is some algorithmic problem in my code, especially using double for loop.

Comment: What is the structure of s (sentences splitted by spacy.sentencizer)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  A self contained example and input data is necessary for the community to easily run the code and focus on answering your question.   [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. I am not familiar with writing here.
I am trying to struggle with this issue by my self. because I found my mistake in the previous coding. 
I will come back if I can't solve my problem by myself
I appreciate very much for you, Taro and Andrews.
I have found what I missed due to your advice